# Error: pg_config executable not found i try to pip3 psycopg2 with python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services, client, psycopg2

im using aws linux , which the default python is 2.7 
I yum installed 3.7 
and changed the alias python=python3
now when I do python -V Im getting: Python 3.7.6. 
i run pip3 install psycopg2

and getting :

```
pip3 install psycopg2
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.5.tar.gz (380 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b3bpay2i/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-b3bpay2i/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3c18jwyz
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-b3bpay2i/psycopg2/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3c18jwyz/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3c18jwyz/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3c18jwyz/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3c18jwyz/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3c18jwyz/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

i try to pip3 the binary 
with : `pip3 install psycopg2-binary`
and did :
 pip3 -list
and the result is :

```
Package         Version Location                                          Installer
--------------- ------- ------------------------------------------------- ---------
pip             20.1    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages            pip
psycopg2-binary 2.8.5   /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages pip
setuptools      38.4.0  /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages                  pip
wheel           0.34.2  /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages pip
```

and when i check if file do exist :

```
ls -l /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 ec2-user ec2-user  302 Apr 30 15:06 psycopg2
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user  102 Apr 30 15:06 psycopg2_binary-2.8.5.dist-info
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Apr 30 15:06 psycopg2_binary.libs
drwxrwxr-x 4 ec2-user ec2-user  233 Apr 30 16:03 wheel
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user  130 Apr 30 16:03 wheel-0.34.2.dist-info
```

also installed postgresql10 client using

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql10
```

why i still getting the error ?

Comment: "pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source" is why you get the error. the -binary package is an alternative, not an additon, you shouldn't have both installed

Comment: what is pg_config  and how do i install it ? do i need also gcc installed ?

Comment: The binary packages come with their own versions of a few C libraries, among which `libpq `and `libssl`, which will be used regardless of other libraries available on the client: upgrading the system libraries will not upgrade the libraries used by `psycopg2`. Build `psycopg2` from source if you want to maintain binary upgradeability.

Comment: And yes, you will need `gcc` installed

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `psycopg2-binary` package is meant for beginners to start playing with `Python` and `PostgreSQL` without the need to meet the build requirements. **For production use you are advised to use the source distribution.**.

Since this package is needed in order to connect to Postgre database, you will need `libpq`. `psycopg2` library is built as a wrapper around `libpq`. It requires some PostgreSQL binaries and headers required for building 3rd-party applications for PostgreSQL. Run:

```py
$ sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev
```

The main goal of the command above is to provide all requirements for building `psycopg2`. To install the latest package in your system, use `pip`:

```py
$ pip3 install psycopg2
```

If you cannot find the `pg_config`, check your PATH. Chances are it is not in your PATH.

On `alpine`, the library containing `pg_config` is [`postgresql-dev`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=postgresql-dev&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=). To install, run:

```py
apk update && \
 apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# Then you can install pyscopg2 say from your requirements.txt file or manually
```

Comment: Why is it not advised to use the binary package for production use?